# Physic: Calculated Waterflow based on Power generation of turbine

Tags: physics

I have a turbine which produces 50MW, the water falls down from three meters height.

How much water does flow per second?

Please *do not answer this question*, but rather give an explanation how I can calculate it myself.

Comment: How is this about mathematics?

Comment: @copper.hat I can't quite follow what your question is. Do you mean why I posted it on Mathematics? As I didn't see a Physics SE. And physic belongs to math. The math is calculating the waterflow.

Comment: And what is the difficulty? It is not about math. It is a physics homework question.

Comment: I don't know how I can get the water flow out of generated Power and fall height.

Comment: What power would be generated if the water flowed at $x$ $m^3/s$? This is basic physics. You need the density of water and the acceleration due to gravity. (Using the usual improbable & unelaborated assumptions of homework questions, presumably in this case the assumption is that all the potential energy is transformed into usable work. Impossible, of course.)

Comment: Mhm. _1 m^3 = 1000 Liters = 1000kg_ so _W=1000*3=3000_ So if I understand right, _50'000'000 / 3000=16666.6.._ Does this mean a waterflow of 16'666L/s or 16qm of water per seconde?

Comment: Doing a dimensional analysis is probably your best bet.

Comment: @TylerKharazi What does this mean? I'm not that good at physics. Could you maybe provide a (simple) formula? Thanks

Comment: This is essentially what you were doing in the comment I upvoted. You should look at the units of power, which are Watts, and the units of Watts are kg m^2/(s^3). Often times in physics, you should look at the units of the problem, they can provide a great intuition for what the final solution ought to look like. Also, FYI there is a physics stack exchange, https://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @TylerKharazi Thanks! So was my calulation correct?

Comment: If your answer does not include $g$ or the density of water $\rho$ then it cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is physics, not math.

If a mass $m$ of water falls through a height $h$ then the potential energy change is
$mgh$.

If $\dot{m}$ of water passes through a height $h$ then the potential energy change per unit time is $\dot{m}gh$.

If water has an average density of $\rho$, and the volume flow rate is $\dot{V}$ then the
mass flow rate is $\dot{m} = \rho \dot{V}$.

If all the potential energy is converted to usable work $P$ in the turbine then we
have $P = \rho \dot{V} gh$.

You have $P,h,g,\rho$. Compute $\dot{V}$.

**Addendum**:

$\rho$ is the density of water, we usually take $\rho = 1000\  kg/m^3$.

$g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, we usually take $g = 9.81 \ m/s^2$.

In the above, $h=3 \ m$, $P= 50 \times 10^6 \ W$.

The dot as in $\dot{m}$ usually means the rate of change with respect to time.
So, $\dot{V}$ is the change of volume per unit time, or flow rate.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand what half of these Letters mean, but I will google them.

Comment: It is more than a little surprising to me that you are doing physics and the letters do not mean anything to you.

Comment: Well, they do say me something. but I'm not sure about conversions and all the stuff. I'm just a normal student in 8th grade.

Comment: Do you know the formula for potential energy of a mass $m$ at height $h$ with acceleration due to gravity $g$?

Comment: I added an explanation of terms, I assumed that you were at the university level, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, this helped :)